# rhythmbox - skip song while shuffling

Tags: music, rhythmbox, tag, media-library

Is it possible to have rhythmbox always skip always skip certain songs while shuffling? Possibly with an mp3 comment tag like "do not shuffle".

I've done some searching for plug-ins but nothing.